# runtime exception handler not invoked

Tags: java, tomcat

My code is like this:

```
    @WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("sdfsfds");                  
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

This is my minimum deployment to ***tomcat 8.0.5***, nothing gets printed in the console. Can anybody give some clue?

Thanks

Comment: Does a normal System.out.println print to your Tomcat logs ?

Comment: I have tested printing system.out and it worked perfectly in tomcat. But for this particular case, it seems nothing gets printed. so it's as if it fails only on tomcat? my tomcat is 8.0.5 btw.

Comment: Can someone help me editing the code? I just cant seem to make it right. Thanks

Comment: How are you submitting the tasks to es? with execute() or submit() ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no console in server so you are not getting anything

But you will get the statements in `catalina.out` file located in the logs folder.

**Note**: if your server is linux machine then you will the *sysout* statements will be printed in the `catalina.out` file

If you server is in windows machine then you will not get *sysout* statements in `catalina.out` file.

You have to manually redirect the console statements to catalina.out file. Follow the below steps

1. create a file and name it as `catalinaRedirectLog.bat`
2. Open it in notepad and type `catalina run > ..\logs\catalina.out 2<&1`
3. save this file
4. run `shutdown.bat`
5. run `catalinaRedirectLog.bat` to start the tomcat,dont run `startup.bat`
   from now onwards

**I would strongly recommend you to use log4 or any other logging frameworks and avoid using sysout statements**

Comment: well, I'm running tomcat from eclipse using eclipse plugin, and normally, I always get the console output in my console tab in eclipse. I also tried writing to log, still nothing, instead, I was redirected to debug perspective as if the thread hung. Thanks

Comment: @Architucas are you running as server or debugging on server?

Comment: when running main, I'm using as Application. It seems that this only happens when I deploy to tomcat. My tomcat is 8.0.5 btw

Comment: updated my question. it seems to be tomcat related issue, have you seen this before?

Comment: @Architucas there are no sysout statements in your updated post

Comment: @Architucas use debugger. my answer will be void now as you have completely changed your post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97176/discussion-between-architucas-and-springlearner).

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` and `System.err` are both redirected to `CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out` when using Tomcat's startup scripts (`bin/startup.sh/.bat or bin/catalina.sh/.bat`). Any code that writes to `System.out` or `System.err` will end up writing to that file.

By default there are no consoles for the Apache Tomcat server. You can however use  `Apache log4j` which is a Java-based logging utility.

Logging in `Apache Tomcat` is implemented with the help of Apache Commons Logging library. That library is a thin wrapper above different logging frameworks. It provides Tomcat with the ability to log hierarchically across various log levels without the need to rely on a particular logging implementation.

You can configure Log4j for Tomcat using the instructions provided in [logging log4j](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)

**EDIT**: (From one of your comments) For configuring logs in your Eclipse console you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501355/log4j-output-not-displayed-in-eclipse-console)

Comment: I have tested printing system.out and it worked perfectly in tomcat. But for this particular case, it seems nothing gets printed. so it's as if it fails only on tomcat? my tomcat is 8.0.5 btw.

Comment: updated my question. it seems to be tomcat related issue, have you seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

How are you submitting tasks to `ExecutorService es`? Through `execute()` or through `submit()`?

If you submit the task through `submit()`, exceptions will be swallowed and they can't reach you.

Have a look at this [Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#FutureTask.Sync.innerRun%28%29)

```
 if (getState() == RUNNING) { // recheck after setting thread
            V result;
            try {
                result = callable.call();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                setException(ex);
                return;
            }
            set(result);
        } else {
            releaseShared(0); // cancel
        }
```

Have a look how to handle Future task [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks). You have to override

```
protected void  afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)
//Method invoked upon completion of execution of the given Runnable.
```

which is part of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)